# Want to add login button only when user input credentials

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make the login button visible only when user enter the credentials in Text Form Field (Email and Password), otherwise login button should be invisible.

[image: LoginPage]

My LoginPage is designed as below:-

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String _email, _password, error = '';
  bool _obscureText = true;
  bool _isKeyboardVisible = true;
  bool _canShowButton = true;
  final AuthenticationService _authenticationService = AuthenticationService();

  _hideWidget(){
    setState(() {
      _canShowButton = !_canShowButton;
    });
  }
  _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  _submit() async {
    if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      dynamic result = await _authenticationService.loginWithEmail(email: _email, password: _password);
      if(result == null) {
        setState(() => error = 'Es wurde kein Benutzerkonto gefunden. Bitte erstellen Sie zuerst das Konto');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
      }
      print(_email);
      print(_password);
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _isKeyboardVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    if(!_isKeyboardVisible) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if(!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus){
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Bitte Melde Dich an",
                    style: TextStyle(color: color, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),),
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 5.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              autofocus: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  )
                                  ),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                  )
                              ),
                              validator: (input) => !EmailValidator.validate(input!, true)
                                  ? 'Please enter valid email'
                                  : null,
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input!,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            const Radius.circular(10.0)
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          _toggle();
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off)
                                    )
                                ),
                                validator: (input) => input!.length < 6
                                    ? 'Must be at least 6 characters': null,
                                onSaved: (input) => _password = input!,
                                obscureText: _obscureText,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 70,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                          child: !_canShowButton ? SizedBox.shrink() : TextButton(
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.white,
                                  backgroundColor: color,
                                  elevation: 5,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _hideWidget();
                              },
                              child: Text('Anmelden')),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if(!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus){
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      'Login Credentials',
                      style: TextStyle(color: color, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    )
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Bitte Melde Dich an",
                    style: TextStyle(color: color, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),),
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 5.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            /*height: _animation.value,*/
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  )
                                  ),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                  )
                              ),
                              // focusNode: _focusNode,
                              validator: (input) => !EmailValidator.validate(input!, true) ? 'Please provide valid email':null,
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input!,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            const Radius.circular(10.0)
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 2.0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          _toggle();
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off)
                                    )
                                ),
                                validator: (input) => input!.length < 6
                                    ? 'Must be at least 6 characters': null,
                                onSaved: (input) => _password = input!,
                                obscureText: _obscureText,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

In short I have added the bool variable and function as below. After that in onPressed of login Button I called `_hideWidget()`.

```
bool _canShowButton = true;
_hideWidget(){
    setState(() {
      _canShowButton = !_canShowButton;
    }); 
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 70,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                          child: !_canShowButton ? SizedBox.shrink() : TextButton(
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.white,
                                  backgroundColor: color,
                                  elevation: 5,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _hideWidget();
                              },
                              child: Text('Anmelden')),
                        ),
                      ),
```

**What I have achieved is:** The Login Button is there on the page and when I click on TextFormField it gets disappear.

**Want to achieve:** Login Button should be invisible on the screen and when user enters the credentials after that it should appear.

Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can tell if there's data in the textfield or not, if there is it'll change `isFilled` to true.

```
bool isFilled = false;
    TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val) {
                 setState(() {
                    (val.isEmpty) ? isFilled = false : isFilled = true;
                 });
                },
                
              )
```

Now to show the button when there's data in the textfield you can use ternary operator.

```
(isFilled)?TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Container()) : Container()
```

Just switch TextButton with your button. Ternary operators work like so

```
(condition) ? (do if true) : (do if false)
```

in this case, you're showing the button if `isFilled = true,` and an empty container if not

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest way of implementing this is to add a TextEdittingController to each Textfield and then render the button only when the TextEdittingController.tex is not empty,when it's empty you can render an empty container otherwise render the button,use a simple tenary operator to do this